# Testing action with redirect gives uexpectable behavior in yii2

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception, yii2-basic-app

I try to test my app with codeception, but all LoginCept.php breaks on this aciton

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->redirect('journal');
    }
}
```

As I can see in the php-buildin-server's logs, after in-app redirect it comes to actual entry point ***index.php*** instead of ***index-test.php***

```
[Thu Jun  9 20:54:00 2016] 127.0.0.1:40472 [302]: /index-test.php/login
[Thu Jun  9 20:54:00 2016] 127.0.0.1:40496 [302]: /index-test.php << in-app redirect
[Thu Jun  9 20:54:00 2016] 127.0.0.1:40506 [500]: /journal
```

So test fails due to this unexpected behavior. How to enforce application's redirects to work at the same entry point script?

Comment: Codeception's behavious is correct. I don't know Yii2, so I don't know if it is possible to make Yii2 to prepend index-test.php/ to redirect urls.

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you using WebDriver or Yii2 module? If WebDriver, then you are using a real browser and it is even more obvious that this behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to wrap URI into ***Url::to()*** to add all stuff, that yii2 uses. So funciton call should looks like this

```
$this->redirect(Url::to('to/something'));
```