# Yii2, Codeception: How to configurate acceptance tests to use the URL of my test server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I want to run functional tests on localhost, but acceptance test on a test server. I changed the configuration of the AcceptanceTester (yii\tests\codeception\frontend\acceptance.suite.yml) from:

```
WebDriver:
    url: 'http://localhost'
```

to:

```
WebDriver:
    url: 'https://test.mydomain.com'
```

When I run the tests, I need to have following URL in the browser:
https://test.mydomain.com/test-page
but I have:
https://test.mydomain.com/yii/frontpage/web/index-test.php/test-page

How can I remove the root **yii/frontpage/web/index-test.php/** from the URL?

Comment: This is a Yii configuration issue.

Comment: I went through all configurations, but I have not found the place, where I could change it.

Comment: I think that this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727689/testing-action-with-redirect-gives-uexpectable-behavior-in-yii2

Comment: I have solved the problem by running the test directly on the test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have solved the problem by configuring the test server to be able to run the acceptance tests:

- I have installed the X Window System and Firefox,
- configured localhost in Apache, so it works with the URL: https://test.mydomain.com/yii/frontpage/web/index-test.php/test-page,
- and adjusted the acceptance Tests, that they work on the test server (added more time in wait commands)

This solution has the advantage, that all my colleagues can run the tests independent from me.